# What is the opposite of Optimal?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Obviously something can be sub-optimal or poor, minimal, bad or terrible... But is there a word that means the exact *opposite*, the antonym, of optimal?

Comment: Hi mystery downvoter, could you please explain why you've downvoted me so I know how I can improve my question?

Comment: afaik, the majority of uses of 'sub-optimal' are (sarcastic) understatement, making the word carry the meaning you're looking for.

Comment: Bollobas, Bela. *Modern Graph Theory*. 1998., "Optimal and **Pessimal** Orderings of Steiner Triple Systems in Disk Arrays" http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pessimal & http://books.google.ca/books?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&id=MbR0qLpZv6kC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=pessimal&prev=http://books.google.ca/books%3Fq%3Dpessimal&sig=tGb9PFkNTjBz3SV09u_Qky3H4Fk

Comment: So you're looking for words like "flawed" or "imperfect" that mean "is not optimal/perfect"?

Comment: @user568458; Ideally I'm interested in a word that means the exact oposite of optimal. So flawed isn't good, it certainly isn't optimal, but is it the most *un*optimal. I guess I'm looking for optimal's perfect antonym

Comment: **Dismal** could also work, but is not, etymologically speaking, an antonym of _optimal_. While it sounds like it'd be related to _optimal_, [it is in fact completely unrelated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dismal).

Comment: I feel like **worst** may not be a bad choice. You know, if you don't want to say megatronic.

Comment: I agree that **worst** is probably a good choice, especially with its much higher extent of common usage. *Optimal* means something like "Most suited to the task/situation", therefore the word desired (and the accepted answer, *pessimal* hits this on the head) must be one which means "*least* suited to the task/situation". Worst doesn't mean exactly that, but it's close enough to be suitable, and much more common.

Comment: I feel like an issue is that there are many problems for which there's a single clearly most-correct way of solving it, but an infinite number of equally wrong ways. Like, if you were trying to pick up a large boulder, both tweezers and a bendy straw are clearly nonoptimal, but I'm not sure I'd be able to make a case for a single idea being the *most* nonoptimal...

Comment: "Pessimal" may not have originated with ["The story of Mel"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html), but it was likely popularized in computing circles by its inclusion in Eric Raymond's web version of the Jargon file.

Comment: @neminem more so, the problem is actually that the pessimal solution is probably trivial. Surely, not trying to pick up the boulder is the worst solution for picking it up.

Comment: If you don't want to use "worst", you could use "sub-optimal", though that's not really an opposite.  People are mentioning the word "pessimal", but native speakers tend to never use that word.  It's a choice between either an opposite for "best" or something that means "less than optimal".

Comment: I think "as bad as possible" is, in some turns of phrase, a better choice than "worst." It may be better writing to substitute a more specific word for "bad" depending on the context: *This algorithm is as slow as possible.* Informally, "maximally bad" is also used.

Comment: "Situation Normal"

Comment: It beats me how "as bad as possible" or "maximually bad" are any different to "worst".   And yet the answer, below, that says 'worst' has only a few votes!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Taking the classical approach, *optimal* derives from *optimus*, the Latin superlative to *bonus*, meaning *good*.

Looking at the Latin for *bad*, that is *malus*.

> bonus -> melior -> optimus
>   malus -> peior -> pessimus

So analogous to *optimus* becoming *optimal*, *pessimus* would become ***pessimal***.

All that said, *I have never heard that word used*.

We do use plenty of the forms of Latin *good* and *bad*, as in *ameliorate*, *pejorative*, *optimal*, *optimist* and *pessimist*.
However, *pessimal* never seems to have made it far in the popularity contests - it *did* get into the dictionaries though!

Comment: Shame it's not in common use, but still, just what I'm looking for

Comment: As a fun fact, *pésimo* (the literal translation of "pessimal" in Spanish) has widespread usage in the language. Great question and even better answer!

Comment: It's a commonly used word in engineering.

Comment: In Maths and Computer Science too

Comment: Seems resonable, there's a whole different world of English usage in the technical fields after all. I like Pessimal, it's clear in it's intended use: positive/negative, optimal/pessimal

Comment: @CLockeWork It's probably not in common use because it's hard to say that something is in it's worst state or has the least capability.  It's easy to say that it's bad, but the worst?  Given the words are by nature more technical terms (and thus wouldn't be used generally as an overstatement), it wouldn't oft be used.

Comment: @Doc, a very good point. I wouldn't expect this be commonly used, or even needed, but it's good to know :)

Comment: FYI, it has the same roots as optimistic/pessimistic.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre - that is why I mentioned them (OK, I mentioned optimist and pessimist) in my answer already ;)

Comment: @oerkelens Oh, my bad, my brain must have just skipped the italic part. Funny how the word exists and is never used though.

Comment: FWIW - Terry Pratchett used Pessimal to name one of his Discworld characters.

Comment: Here is an "actual" example of _pessimal_ being used as opposite of _optimal_: http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/fa05/cs473ug/resources/pessimal-algorithms.pdf

Comment: In the context of computing, I have also come across _pessimization_ as a somewhat tongue-in-cheek opposite of optimization

Comment: I'm going to start saying pessimal now

Comment: Dito @Claudiu :)

Comment: Edward Tufte claims [here](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0003uY) to have co-invented the word in 1963. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/242412) traces it to 1921, and says that it is chiefly used in science. But they do have this 1977 quotation from _The Times:_ "If they wish to avoid the ultimate absurdity of building Utopia in the pessimal image of the National Union of Journalists."

Comment: @BenKovitz Hahaha, thanks for the research.  I thought I was the one who had to get out more... but that's the pessimal solution: far better to stay in and trawl the Net till the early hours for obscure philological knowledge.

Answer (score 22):

Since pessimal is correct in the worst possible way, I would look more carefully at the specific usage.  One common antonym in discussions of algorithms that would probably fit many usages is "**worst-case**."  You will often see optimal and worst-case performance contrasted as well as optimal (aka best-case) scenarios and worst-case scenarios.

Comment: A very good point mmdanziger :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you simply had not understood the meaning of "optimal". It's just a elevated synonym of "best". (from Latin "optimus") And its antonym is simply "worst".

Comment: It's ironic that the more high-falutin' word "pessimal" gets the votes, when here is a plain old word that is the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

exact opposite of "optimal" is "non-optimal"

Comment: Thanks for your input indian, but [Non-optimal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonoptimal) means not optimal, even a tiny point off of optimal can be said to be non-optimal so non-optimal isn't the *opposite* of optimal

Comment: @CLockeWork: While I don't believe this is a good answer, I would argue that it isn't always clear what *opposite* **really** means. There are many cases where "even a tiny point off optimal" is completely unacceptable and utterly wrong, and being two or three or a million points off optimal is no worse.

Comment: A good point @JohnY, while I wanted be clear that I was looking for the technical antonym of the word, in an emotional context there's a whiole lot of wiggle room there.

Answer (score 1):

pessimal.

google the word. it should fit your need.

Comment: Am I crazy or didn't this answer occur before the one with 76 votes that comes to the same conclusion? I realize the other answer is more thorough, but still...

Comment: @TTT if that's the case, it just shows how a complete, well explained answer is rewarded for its effects. And vickvace, I wish you would at least capitalize the first letter in a sentence, this is ELU not Yahoo.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that's exactly it; if multiple answers are the same then the most complete and thorough one gets my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

It may not always be applicable, but "pathological" may be a good choice.

If something is optimal, it is a/the best combination of all relevant factors.

If something is pathological, it is a/the worst combination of all relevant factors.

Comment: [Pathological doesn't mean that.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pathological?s=t)

Comment: [yes it does](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/pathological.html), in hacker jargon.

Comment: @PhilFrost I don't think so - all three variants allow that there are multiple pathological cases, each very bad, but not exactly in the same way. The "un-optimal" case is only one, or at least multiple cases that are exactly as bad as the others - that's the essence.

Comment: @DJClayworth It does mean that in mathematics and computer science: see the "slang dictionary" and "computing dictionary" entries of the page you link (which appear to be identical).

Comment: I intended it in the Mathematical sense http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_(mathematics) although the jargon file pretty much matches that: something which goes completely against what you were trying to achieve, whilst still obeying all the conditions you imposed.

Comment: "a pathological case occurred where the vibration caused the autopilot to fail and the aircraft to crash. Later in the test a pessimal case occurred where the aircraft opened a portal to the demon dimension and ended the world, the cause of this is as-yet unknown" (Although in everyday speech this is the answer that people would actually understand so +1)

Comment: I agree with @DJClayworth, it doesn't mean that even in mathematics.  There can be many different pathological cases; none of them may be the worst possible one.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust on WordNet (http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/):

optimum, optimal (most desirable possible under a restriction expressed or implied)

antonym:
worst [Indirect via best] ((superlative of `bad') most wanting in quality or value or condition) "the worst player on the team"; "the worst weather of the year"

Answer (score -1):

Generally this requires a sentence, because as tribal monkeys we like to dwell on bad situations and defeats.

> *It was the very abject point of hopelessness*
>
> *things were as bad as they could ever be*
>
> *he had given up all hope*

But here are some words you could try; **Horrid**, **abject**, **hopeless**, **worst**, **dreadful**, **awful**, **woebegone**, **abysmal**, **dire**.

Comment: All the suggestions are in the spirit of the request correct, but are not precise and seemingly subjective (which is, of course, my subjective opinion to be precise ;).

Answer (score -1):

Around here (IT department) the phrase *the Murphy way of doing things* is commonly used as opposite of *the optimal way of doing things*.

Derived obviously from "Murphy's Law":
Anything that *can* go wrong, *will* go wrong, at the worst possible moment, causing maximum damage.

May not be generally suitable, but for us it works.

Comment: That's not Murphy's Law. Murphy's Law is that *people* will do the wrong thing, at least some of the time, if given the opportunity. It's a design principle (don't give them the opportunity).

Comment: @JonHanna: My memory, and wikipedia, disagree with you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law

Comment: @MooingDuck that link agrees with me.

Comment: First sentence on the page uses "Anything that can go wrong will go wrong.".  The examples in the History section are "everything goes wrong at sea with regard to machinery" "All results will happen with enough experiments" "Everything goes wrong when performing" "Everything goes wrong with mountaineering" "Everything goes wrong as a law of thermodynamics", the only example referring to a person making mistakes that I see is the last "He will make every mistake".  Do you interpret the others in that section as _only_ human error?  I don't see it...

Comment: The "Association with Murphy" section does definitely suggest that the origin was a person doing the wrong thing every time as you say, but it is merely one of many theories as to the _origin_ of the common phrase, and not a discussion of the term phrase (In my opinion).  If you disagree, I'd be interesting in learning.  Probably in chat though since I think we're no longer quite on topic.

Answer (score -1):

In that situation, I use the phrase ***'perfect storm'***. As in:

> I was unprepared and late for the meeting already, and then he told me it was moved up an hour. It was the perfect storm.

Of course, you cannot use it in a formal context, but otherwise it comes close to conveying the meaning you want.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, but a [Perfect Storm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_storm) is a confluence of events coming together to make a situation far worse. This isn't to say the situation is the exact opposite of optimal.

Comment: I know it's not the ideal antonym. That's why I said "I'd use..." and "comes close".

Comment: I'm sorry, @Tushar. It's more that I don't see how a `perfect storm` relates at all :(