# What's the opposite of bonus?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, antonyms

According to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178305/what-is-the-opposite-of-optimal), the antonym would be Malus. But is there a more widely used term?

Consider an exam where you've got a "Bonus question", so solving it correctly gives you an extra point. Would it be called a "Malus question": solving it incorrectly deducts a point (as opposed to giving no points)? Or is there a better way to describe that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Penalty"

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bonus?s=t

Interesting concept,  "Penalty Avoidance Question".

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Helpful hint: don't phrase answers as questions; the system automatically flags such answers. Be definite, and provide a corroborative citation.